# Decrypt AES-256-CFB in PHP with openssl instead mcrypt

Tags: php, encryption, aes, mcrypt, php-openssl

The function below correctly decrypt the data in php5

```
function decrypt_mcrypt($key, $str) {
  $str = base64_decode($str);
  $iv = substr($str, 0, 16);
  $str = substr($str, 16);
  return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $iv);
}
```

I tried to use openssl instead of mcrypt (in php7), but got garbage on the output.

```
function decrypt_openssl($key, $str) {
  $str = base64_decode($str);
  $iv = substr($str, 0, 16);
  $str = substr($str, 16);
  return openssl_decrypt($str, 'AES-256-CFB', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`openssl_decrypt` uses PKCS#5 padding, where as `mcrypt` pads messages with zeros.

Try using the `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` option when using `openssl_decrypt` as per [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php).

Comment: tried  openssl_decrypt($str, 'AES-256-CFB', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);  and openssl_decrypt($str, 'AES-256-CFB', $key, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);  - did not help